# Inner select too slow in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have tried a few ways to do this using `group by` / `sum over` but none of them perform.

If I remove the `rollingQty` it returns all 1.5 million records in 9 seconds however the below statement is still running 30 minutes in. Is there a way to streamline this query for better performance?

```
SELECT sol.sales_order_quantity AS sales_order_quantity,
       sol.business_unit_key AS business_unit_key,
       sol.order_date_key AS order_date_key,
       sol.ship_day_key AS ship_day_key,
       sol.promised_ship_day_key AS promised_ship_day_key,
       sol.part_key AS part_key,
       sol.sales_order_line_classification_key AS sales_order_line_classification_key,
       sol.last_supplier_key AS last_supplier_key,
       sol.part_description AS part_description,
       sol.unit_price_usd AS unit_price_usd,
       sol.customer_discount_usd AS customer_discount_usd,
       sol.sales_order_number,
       sol.sales_order_line,
       sol.shipping_record_id,
       ISNULL(
       (
           SELECT SUM(solp.sales_order_quantity)
           FROM edap_dw.fact_sales_order_line solp
               INNER JOIN edap_dw.fact_sales_order_header sohp
                   ON solp.business_unit_key = sohp.business_unit_key
                      AND solp.sales_order_number = sohp.sales_order_number
                       AND ISNULL(sohp.Drop_ship, 'NO') <> 'YES'
           WHERE (sol.part_key) = solp.part_key
           AND (solp.sales_order_quantity * solp.unit_price_usd) <> 0
                 AND (sol.order_date_key) >= solp.order_date_key
                 AND (sol.order_date_key) <= CASE
                                                 WHEN solp.ship_day_key = -1 THEN
                                                     FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yyyyMMdd')
                                                 ELSE
                                                     solp.ship_day_key
                                             END
       ),
       0
             ) AS rollingQty
FROM edap_dw.fact_sales_order_line sol
WHERE sol.order_date_key > 20191231
AND (sol.sales_order_quantity * sol.unit_price_usd) <> 0
AND CASE
          WHEN sol.business_unit_key = 10
               AND sol.sales_order_number LIKE '%-%' THEN
              0
          ELSE
              1
      END = 1
```

Due to a lot of comments on this here is a simplified version of the SQL which performs just as badly.

```
SELECT sol.sales_order_number,
       sol.sales_order_line,
       sol.shipping_record_id,
       ISNULL(
       (
           SELECT SUM(solp.sales_order_quantity)
           FROM edap_dw.fact_sales_order_line solp
               INNER JOIN edap_dw.fact_sales_order_header sohp
                   ON solp.business_unit_key = sohp.business_unit_key
                      AND solp.sales_order_number = sohp.sales_order_number
           WHERE (sol.part_key) = solp.part_key
                 AND (sol.order_date_key) >= solp.order_date_key
                 AND (sol.order_date_key) <= CASE
                                                 WHEN solp.ship_day_key = -1 THEN
                                                     20230921
                                                 ELSE
                                                     solp.ship_day_key
                                             END
       ),
       0
             ) AS rollingQty
FROM edap_dw.fact_sales_order_line sol
WHERE sol.order_date_key > 20191231
```

The question is how can we get the total quantity of the part per sales order line that is between the sales order created date and the ship date. Sudo code is welcome.

I did try use a sum over but was unable to add the greater then order date filter.

```
WITH SalesOrderLines
AS (SELECT sol.sales_order_quantity AS sales_order_quantity,
           sol.business_unit_key AS business_unit_key,
           sol.order_date_key AS order_date_key,
           sol.ship_day_key AS ship_day_key,
           sol.promised_ship_day_key AS promised_ship_day_key,
           sol.part_key AS part_key,
           sol.sales_order_line_classification_key AS sales_order_line_classification_key,
           sol.last_supplier_key AS last_supplier_key,
           sol.part_description AS part_description,
           sol.unit_price_usd AS unit_price_usd,
           sol.customer_discount_usd AS customer_discount_usd,
           sol.sales_order_number,
           sol.sales_order_line,
           sol.shipping_record_id,
           CASE
               WHEN sol.ship_day_key = -1 THEN
                   FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yyyyMMdd')
               ELSE
                   sol.ship_day_key
           END CalculatedShipDate,
           ISNULL(soh.Drop_ship, 'NO') IsDropShip,
           CASE
               WHEN ISNULL(soh.Drop_ship, 'NO') <> 'YES' THEN
                   sol.sales_order_quantity
               ELSE
                   0
           END CalculatedSalesQuantity
    FROM edap_dw.fact_sales_order_line sol
        INNER JOIN edap_dw.fact_sales_order_header soh
            ON sol.business_unit_key = soh.business_unit_key
               AND sol.sales_order_number = soh.sales_order_number
    WHERE sol.order_date_key > 20191231
          AND (sol.sales_order_quantity * sol.unit_price_usd) <> 0
          AND CASE
                  WHEN sol.business_unit_key = 10
                       AND sol.sales_order_number LIKE '%-%' THEN
                      0
                  ELSE
                      1
              END = 1)
SELECT *,
       sol.sales_order_quantity,
       SUM(sol.CalculatedSalesQuantity) OVER (PARTITION BY sol.business_unit_key,
                                                           sol.part_key
                                              ORDER BY sol.business_unit_key,
                                                       sol.part_key,
                                                       sol.CalculatedShipDate,
                                                       sol.sales_order_number
                                             ) rollingQty
FROM SalesOrderLines sol
ORDER BY sol.business_unit_key,
         sol.part_key,
         sol.CalculatedShipDate;
```

Comment: Does `1.5 mil` mean `1.5 million records`? Please don't use unnecessary and possibly unclear abbreviations. And if so, it might mean the `rollingQty` query gets executed 1.5 million times.

Comment: The query is written in a way that can't use any indexes. Comparing values with function results, or filtering by the results of big CASE expressions means the server has to scan all records to calculate the expression results before it can find matches. And `sales_order_number LIKE '%-%'` can't use any index because it searches in the middle of a string

Comment: that `ISNULL(` wrapper seems weird to me here.

Comment: What you essentially have is per-row subquery, like correlated one. What you should try is to rethink your approach to use inline view with join instead

Comment: And even worse, judging by the table names, you're joining a fact table to itself. Why? What kind of results are you trying to produce?

Comment: Please post the schema of the fact table, the dimensions, and what you want to calculate. You should only include the fact table once, join only to the dimensions, filter by the *dimension* fields, not the fact table keys, *not* try to replace nulls before filtering. *Don't* filter unindexed columns, especially if they have no effect. `solp.sales_order_quantity * solp.unit_price_usd) <> 0` only forces a full table scan for no benefit.

Comment: In that `CASE`  `FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yyyyMMdd')` and later `WHERE sol.order_date_key > 20191231` this is a weird mix of types - feels like they should ALL be a `DATE` type

Comment: What are you grouping by? If you want to include the order total on every line item, use `SUM(sales_order_quantity) OVER(Partition by sol.part_key)`, don't execute a SUM on every line.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss this is a date dimension key. It could be a `date` but there's no harm to a `numeric(8)` *provided it's used properly*. Right now it's not used properly. I bet `-1` is the `N/A` entry

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  Yes,  regarding that -1 but also a weird mix where they might cast to the key type.

Comment: I am quite aware of the design flaws of this data warehouse but I still need a running total that calculates the quantity used for the part on the sales order for all sales orders that exist between the order creation date and the ship date

Comment: If you have a way to do a sum over using the logic of the sum only calculating the values between the create date and ship date then post it and I will see if I can apply it.

Comment: it feels like you should be able to use a window running aggregation function for this. could you post some samples of the data?

Answer (score 0):

Not a full evaluation (so just community wiki), but this predicate stood out:

```
(sol.order_date_key) <= CASE
                             WHEN solp.ship_day_key = -1 THEN
                                  FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yyyyMMdd')
                              ELSE
                                  solp.ship_day_key
                          END
```

It tells me you have date values stored as integers, are are relying on implicit conversions between character and numeric/date values. That's **always** going to be measurably slower than keeping things as real `date` columns and types, especially as it also means the column is likely not properly indexed.

---

Separately, the `rollingQty` name is telling. Thanks to windowing functions, there are now newer and *much faster* ways to compute running/rolling totals, ie `SUM() OVER (...)`. This will likely make an order of magnitude level improvement in computing that column.

---

Minor but

```
AND CASE
          WHEN sol.business_unit_key = 10
               AND sol.sales_order_number LIKE '%-%' THEN
              0
          ELSE
              1
      END = 1
```

Can perhaps be

```
AND NOT (sol.business_unit_key = 10 AND sol.sales_order_number LIKE '%-%')
```

Comment: This looks like a date dimension key, with `-1` being the N/A value. I'd bet the actual key is a `numeric(8)`, not a string. The entire expression is wrong

Comment: Its a star schema format dates are kept as integers this is normal when linking to a date dim table.

Comment: @Jed it's the conversions to and from varchar that are slowing you down most there. You can use integers (if you must) without also cycling to and from strings.

Comment: I updated the sql to a more simplied version

Comment: It's the entire idea of summing per row as if this was a 100-row table, not a 1M row fact table. `sol.business_unit_key = 10 AND sol.sales_order_number LIKE '%-%'` looks like an attempt to filter special order types, which should be a separate dimension in itself. It probably is already, but somehow the OP assumed it would be faster to filter the fact table, not the dimensions. The rolling sum subquery looks like an attempt to include the *pending* total for each shipment, so it includes order lines shipped *after* the current one, along with unshipped lines

Comment: Please see the simplified SQL this is not the issue.

Comment: @Jed again, what are you trying to do? Don't make people guess what you're asking. You can't fix this by changing one line. If you explain the *business* problem, people can easily write an efficient answer that only scans the fact table once, and only includes rows filtered by dimensions

Comment: @Jed if your SQL contains a fact table twice, it's wrong. The "simplified" query is no different than the original, executing 1M individual full-table SUMs. `SUM OVER()` will replace the *entire* `ISNULL(.....)` subquery.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The question is how can we get the total quantity of the part per sales order line that is between the sales order created date and the ship date. Sudo code is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up generating a table off the date time dim and a cte of the sales order line with my filters applied.

```
open_order_dates
    AS (SELECT  sol.part_key,
                sol.business_unit_key,
                dtd.time_day_key order_open_date_key,
                SUM(sol.sales_order_quantity) order_open_quantity
        FROM    sales_order_lines sol
            INNER JOIN edap_dw.dim_time_day AS dtd ON dtd.time_day_key BETWEEN sol.order_date_key AND sol.ship_day_key
        GROUP BY sol.business_unit_key,
                 sol.part_key,
                 dtd.time_day_key
```

then I joined to this table

```
SELECT  sol.*, ood.order_open_quantity
FROM    SalesOrderLines sol
LEFT JOIN OpenOrderDates ood ON ood.business_unit_key = sol.business_unit_key AND ood.part_key = sol.part_key AND ood.order_open_date_key = sol.order_date_key
ORDER BY sol.business_unit_key,
         sol.part_key,
         sol.CalculatedShipDate;
```

This gives me the same result in around 2 minutes